# gensimのインストールが成功していない

Tags: python, macos, pip

```
sudo pip install gensim
```

でgensimをインストールしようとしたのですがエラーが出てうまくいかず,
http://qiita.com/kawashinji/items/98fd8a917a17c3476091
この方と似ていたので同じように対処したところ,Successfullyと表示されました.
しかし,確認のためにターミナルで import してみたところ,下記のエラーが表示されました.
対処法等,分かる方がいましたら教えてください.

```
>>> import gensim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .word2vec import Word2Vec
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 108, in <module>
    from gensim.models.word2vec_inner import train_batch_sg, train_batch_cbow
  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init gensim.models.word2vec_inner (./gensim/models/word2vec_inner.c:10913)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 88, got 96
```

Comment: numpy のバージョンが古いのではないでしょうか。`pip show gensim` で見ると `numpy, scipy, six, smart-open` パッケージに依存しているので、`pip install --upgrade numpy scipy smart-open` としてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます. numpy アップグレードでもエラーが出てきてしまい,こちらを試しています.
qiita.com/myoshimu/items/80bebee237e22b72b245